# Custom Script Extension fails when executing ARM template

Tags: azure, azure-powershell

I'm in the process of building some ARM templates to use when deploying servers within our environment. I have a successful server build script and am trying to add in a Custom Script Extension to perform some post build configuration.

Below is the Powershell script I am running to execute the build

```
resourceGroupName = "xxx-preprod-xxx-rg"
New-AzResourceGroupDeployment  -ResourceGroupName $resourceGroupName `
-TemplateFile "C:\Users\Username\Azure Deployments\IaaS\Server Build/cadeploy.json" `
-TemplateParameterFile "C:\Users\Username\Azure Deployments\IaaS\Server Build/gwc.cadeploy.parameters.json"
```

While the server build is successful, the execution of the Custom Script Extension is failing with the following error.

*New-AzResourceGroupDeployment : 9:47:45 AM - The deployment 'cadeploy' failed with error(s). Showing 1 out of 1 error(s).
Status Message: VM has reported a failure when processing extension 'CustomScriptExtension'. Error message: "Finished executing command"
More information on troubleshooting is available at https://aka.ms/VMExtensionCSEWindowsTroubleshoot  (Code:VMExtensionProvisioningError)
CorrelationId: 7740dee6-3fe6-4ec9-9238-d8bca401af91
At line:2 char:1

New-AzResourceGroupDeployment  -ResourceGroupName $resourceGroupName  ...

```
  + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [New-AzResourceGroupDeployment], Exception
  + FullyQualifiedErrorId : Microsoft.Azure.Commands.ResourceManager.Cmdlets.Implementation.NewAzureResourceGroupDeploymentCmdlet*
```

Below is the code snippet for the Custom Script Execution

```
"type": "Microsoft.Compute/virtualMachines/extensions",
            "name": "[concat(parameters('virtualMachine_name'),'/CustomScriptExtension')]",
            "apiVersion": "2015-05-01-preview",
            "location": "[parameters('regionLocation')]",
            "dependsOn": [
                "[concat('Microsoft.Compute/virtualMachines/',parameters('virtualMachine_name'))]"
        ],
            "properties": {
            "publisher": "Microsoft.Compute",
            "type": "CustomScriptExtension",
            "typeHandlerVersion": "1.4",
            "settings": {
                 "fileUris": [
                    "https://dev.azure.com/companyname/_git/RepoName?path=/Folder%20Name/Enable-Telnet.ps1"
            ],
            "commandToExecute": "powershell.exe -ExecutionPolicy Unrestricted -File Enable-Telnet.ps1"
            }
```

As you can see, I am trying to pull the script to execute from Azure Repos. Below is the content of the .ps1 file. It's a simple script to enable Telnet.

```
set-executionpolicy remotesigned
dism /online /Enable-Feature /FeatureName:TelnetClient
```

While troubleshooting, I checked out the content of what was trying to execute on the target server from the following location - C:\Packages\Plugins\Microsoft.Compute.CustomScriptExtension\1.4\Downloads\6\Enable-Telnet.ps1

The content of that file is shown below.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" dir="ltr"  lang="en-US" >

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8" />
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />
  <meta name="msapplication-config" content="none" />
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
  <meta name="robots" content="none" />
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
  <link id="page-icon" rel="shortcut icon"  href="https://cdn.vsassets.io/content/icons/favicon.ico"  />
  
  <meta name="referrer" content="strict-origin-when-cross-origin" /><script data-description="contentInit" nonce="ohQVCuUueS04MokMIfRnFg==">window.$DEBUG = false;window.__scriptType = "ES2017";window.__moduleNamespaces = ["create-react-class","prop-types","react","react-dom","react-dom-factories","react-transition-group","tslib","VSS/Core","@azure/msal-browser","msal-browser","mousetrap","VSS/Platform","VSSUI","VSS/Legacy","VSS/Features/PlatformUI","Tfs/Platform","VSS/Features","Search/LegacyWebApi","Search/Coordinator","Tfs/Header/Components","VSS/Features/Search","VSS/Features/Services","Tfs/Frame","VSS/Ext","TFS/GlobalBanner","Favorites/Common","Favorites/Dropdown","Repos/Common","Repos/RepoDropdown","Repos/ChangesCommon","Repos/Files","Repos/FilesHubCommon","Repos/Messages","Repos/VersionDropdown","VSS/Features/MonacoWidgets","VSS/Features/Identities","TFS/Admin/Common","TFS/Admin/OrganizationAadCommon","xss","TFS/Admin/Views/OrganizationAad","Repos/Views/FilesHub","TFS/Services"];window.__asyncModules = [];window.__extensionsStaticRoot = "https://cdn.vsassets.io/ext/";window.__extensionsLocalStaticRoot = "/globalratesetsystems/_static/_ext/";window.__useAadToken = false;window.resourceLoadStrategy = 'scriptsFirst';var preTraceServiceStartErrors = []; var onPreTraceServiceError = function (event) { preTraceServiceStartErrors.push(event) }; window.addEventListener('error', onPreTraceServiceError);var previousResourceLoadCompletion = window.performance.now(); var resourceLoadTimes = {}; window.logResourceLoad = function (id) {var now = window.performance.now(); resourceLoadTimes[id] = { current: now, previous: previousResourceLoadCompletion }; previousResourceLoadCompletion = now; }; </script><script data-description="disableCdn" nonce="ohQVCuUueS04MokMIfRnFg==">function cdnReload(fromTimeout) { 
document.cookie = 'TFS-CDN=disabled;max-age=28800;path=/;secure'; 
document.cookie = 'TFS-CDNTRACE=report;path=/;secure'; 
if(fromTimeout){document.cookie = 'TFS-CDNTIMEOUT=report;path=/;secure'; }
document.location.reload(true); 
}
var cdnTimeout = setTimeout(function () { cdnReload(true); }, 10000);</script>  

…… (over 100k of text removed for brevity) …….

  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
  <title>Files</title>
</head>

<body class="lwp fluent-icons-enabled">
  <noscript><div class="absolute-fill flex-column flex-center"><h2>JavaScript is Disabled</h2><p>Please enable javascript and refresh the page</p></div></noscript>
  <input type="hidden" name="__RequestVerificationToken" value="9W3u_D1KurReNa-C8GFmtM-ZrqDbmrjAEracN8TJSxu6J9KmnJ_paGT7DmSortKnvr9uqNJTfJc3sk4BMAlsTeVUZAvptG4tiLHoHI8NKno1" /><input type="hidden" name="__RequestVerificationToken2" value="__RequestVerificationToken24f8e6f64-a78a-4b62-b522-d3001828a4d1" />
  <div data-componentregion="page" class="full-size"></div>
  <div class="bolt-portal-host absolute-fill no-events scroll-hidden"></div>
</body>

</html>
```

Does anyone have any idea why the resultant downloaded file would look like this, as it bears no resemblance to the original script is appears to be causing the script execution failure.